# HTML Form to XML File done, how do I post XML File to webserver?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I've created a form based on edits from another post I found on here, where the HTML form outputs in XML format once the submit button has been clicked. How do I now take this data once transformed and post it to a third-party server via HTTP POST instead of outputting on html?

My code in its current form can be found here.
http://jsbin.com/iyokay/15/edit

My knowledge of Javascript isn't great so any code based help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? `$.ajax({url:"third-party", type:"POST", contentType:"text/xml", data:newXml)`

Comment: No nothing yet. I've been hunting around for a solution without any joy, so resorted to asking a question on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send your xml with ajax,

```
$("#DownloadButton").on("click",function(){
     xml = update();
     $.ajax({
       url : "saveXml.php",
       type:"post",
       data : xml,
       contentType: "text/xml",
       success : function(response){
          alert("xml saved successfully");
       }  
     });
});
```

replace this `$("#DownloadButton").click(update);` with above code

Comment: how do i reference in ajax?

Comment: well how do I integrate that code into what I already have? Is there an ajax library that has to be referenced?

Comment: Don't forget to set the `contentType`.

Comment: @sagamon: you tagged your question [tag:jQuery], and jQuery has a [powerful ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Don't you use it?

Comment: @sagamon you don't need any  library,, jQuery is enough.

Comment: no although I guess I'm about to. I'm a bit of noob when it comes to java

Comment: wait.. i am updating my answer